# The association between User and Contact model sound and correct?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, associations

Two models, `User` and `Contact` in `postgres` and `sequelize`. A contact is a user and it has a owner (my_id) and may have multiple contacts.

```
Contact: {
  my_id, integer
  contact_user_id: integer
}

User: {
  id: integer
  name: string
}
```

Here is the associations defined:

```
  Contact.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: "my_id"});
  Contact.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: "contact_user_id"});
  User.hasMany(Contact, {foreignKey: "contact_user_id"});
  User.hasOne(Contact, {foreignKey: "my_id"});
```

A contact has 2 `belongsTo` association with `User` through `my_id` and `contact_user_id` respectively. Also a user `hasMany` contacts and `hasOne` owner contact at the same time. Are those association sound and correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly so.  You'll need to add an `as:` parameter to these associations (and use these values when querying) so Sequelize can determine which join is appropriate.

For example:

```
  User.hasMany(Contact, {as: 'contactFor', foreignKey: "contact_user_id"});
  User.hasOne (Contact, {as: 'mycontact',  foreignKey: "my_id"}); 

  User.findAll({
     where: {'id' : 1},
     include: [{ model: Contact, as: 'contactFor'}]
  });
```

The above query will give show user 1 and all the contacts who list user 1 as their contact.... the generated query will say something like:

```
 SELECT * FROM user JOIN contact 
 ON user.id = contact.contact_user_id 
 WHERE user.id = 1
```

HTH

Comment: `KenOn10`, can you give an example with `as`? I have concern with 2 belongsTo and hasOne and hasMany at the same time. Is there design change I can apply to avoid those seemly duplicate association between 2 models? Thanks.